# Couldn't read firebase child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Users can able to data when they login in. But I want everyone can able to this child.No matter logged in.

Child is "gunluksifreler"

Here are my rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Homeland": {
       ".indexOn": ["username","email","bakiyetl","yarismada","yarismadabb","splashmesaj","uygulama1tut","uygulama2tut","uygulama3tut","uygulama4tut","uygulama5tut","uygulama6tut","uygulama7tut","uygulama8tut","uygulama9tut","uygulama10tut"]
        },
   "Odultalepleri": {
       ".indexOn": ["username","odul1"]
        },
    "Yardim": {
       ".indexOn": ["id"]
        },      
    "gunluksifreler": {
      ".read": true, // <-- allows every person
      ".write": true
    },
      "Devices": {
      ".read": true, // <-- allows every person
      ".write": true
    },
      ".read": "auth !== null", // <-- allows read if logged in
      ".write": "auth !== null" // <-- allows write if logged in
  }
}
```

It can be read for everyone when I set true last read line

```
".read": true, // <-- allows read everbody
".write": "auth !== null" // <-- allows write if logged in
```

But this time everyone can read every child. What I'm missing?

Code

```
var kullanici = firebase.database().ref();
kullanici.on('value' ,function(datasnapshot) {
     if(datasnapshot.hasChild("gunluksifreler")){
         alert("yes");
     }});
```

But it's not about the code it's about the rules.

Comment: I'm having a hard time parsing your use-case. Can you edit your question to include the **code** for an operation that you want to allow, and for an operation that you want to deny?

Comment: Code is worked fine.It's about rules.I'm trying to make access to "gunluksifreler" for everyone.It work when I change ".read": "auth !== null", to ".read": true, But this time other child are not in safe.

Comment: I'm not saying your code is wrong, but can't judge your rules without seeing the code. Rules on themselves are meaningless without seeing the code that is used against it.

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: Thanks. Is this an operation that you want to allow? Does it work? Also: can you `console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)` right before attaching that listener, to see if the user is indeed logged in.

Comment: It says "currentuser null".Actualy I'm trying to access this child on the non-login page.So this page only includes firebase config and code which is I shared on first post.But if you ask "Do you get the user id on user logged in the page" Yes I can see.But I'm trying to deal with non-login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want anonymous users to be able to read the entire database, you should **not** allow `"read": true` at the root level in your security rules.

Then if you want to allow everyone to read `kullanici`, you should allow `"read": true` on that node in your rules.

So this part of your original rules looks fine to me:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "gunluksifreler": {
      ".read": true
    },
    ".read": "auth !== null"
  }
}
```

*I highly recommend focusing the rules/code in your question similarly in the future, as it ensures we're both looking at the same minimal-but-complete fragment.*

The problem is not in the rules, but in your code:

```
var kullanici = firebase.database().ref();
kullanici.on('value', ...
```

This is trying to read the root of the database, which the rules explicitly disallow. So this read gets rejected.

A good way to remember this is that [Firebase security rules don't on their own filter any data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters). They merely check whether the read you're trying to do is allows. So the read above tries to read the root, which is not allowed. Firebase doesn't check every child node of the root to only return allowed child data, as the performance of that would be hard to guarantee.

If you want read the `kullanici` node, you should attach your listener to *only* that node:

```
var kullanici = firebase.database().ref("kullanici");
kullanici.on('value', ...
```

Comment: I said "it's not about the code" but I was wrong.I haven't had my coffee yet.Thank you.